# Click once WPF application (available offline) – Mounting previous versions in the “Application Files” folder – Team City

Tags: wpf, deployment, clickonce, teamcity

We are currently building a WPF application which is to be deployed via Click Once, the build is currently being handled by a Team City server.
We are noticing that every time someone checks in some code and the CI server builds the deployment package, the “Application Files” directory contains an additional version of the application.

**Due to the mounting size of Click Once deployment, this is becoming un-scalable, does anyone have any idea how to limit the number of previous versions that are placed inside the Application Files directory?**

The application files directory:

[image: The application files screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Click Once does not provide any mechanism for handling the published deployments. It would be difficult for Microsoft to do that, because everybody's requirements would be different. I'm sure that's why Team City didn't add that ability either (assuming they didn't, I don't use Team City).